# Difficulty in finding Candidate Keys

Tags: normalization

I have an homework which should be submitted tomorrow I normaly know normalization concepts but in some questions I have difficulty. How should i normalize this to BCNF? Can you show the steps please?

```
R(A,B,C,D,E,F,H)
```

Functional dependencies are

```
A->D
AE->H
DF->BC
E->C
H->E
```

I found 2 candidate Keys which are `AFH` and `AFE`. Is this correct? I must be sure that my candidate keys are correct to continue to normalization.

Comment: re-tagged as homework

Comment: @StuartBlackler http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/828/is-the-homework-tag-deprecated-on-dba-se